# Expanding a product formally.

Tags: summation, products

Let $a_1,...,a_n$ be real numbers.

I don't know how to formally expand the following product

$$ \prod_{k=1}^n(1+a_k) $$

I'm guessing something like (edited) $$1+\huge\sum_{k=1}^n \; \huge\sum_{1\leq j_1<...<j_k\leq n}a_{j_1}...a_{j_k}$$

But I'm not sure. Can someone check ?

Comment: you are missing a "one"

Comment: @rlartiga right. Is the rest valid ?

Comment: It should be $1 \leqslant j_1 < \dotsc < j_k \leqslant n$. Some products include the term $a_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add $1$ to the sum. You obtain it selecting $1$ in every term of the product.

Perhaps you prefer this expression. Let be $S=\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Then, the expansion gives:
$$\sum_{T\subset S}\prod_{k\in T} a_k$$
The term you have forgotten is when $T=\emptyset$.

Comment: Did you mean $S={1,...,n}$ ?

Comment: Yes, thank you.