# Expanding linear factors of polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I am attempting to expand the polynomial
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\varepsilon a_k)$$
in a way that I can collect the $O(1),O(\varepsilon),O(\varepsilon^2)$ terms and so on. I feel as though this would be a direct application of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754760/expanding-a-product-formally) but don't fully understand the notation and how this reindexing would effect the result. Here is my attempt!
$$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\varepsilon a_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(1-\varepsilon a_{k-1})=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{1\leq j_1<\cdots <j_k \leq n-1}(-\varepsilon a_{j_1})\cdots(-\varepsilon a_{j_k}).$$
I was hoping someone may be able to help me see what the first few terms would look like. I am not overly familiar with the $\sum_{1\leq j_1<\cdots <j_k \leq n-1}$ notation.

Comment: FWIW that's $\,\varepsilon^n P\left(\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)\,$ where $\,\displaystyle P(x) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x - a_k)\,$.

Comment: While getting used to such expansions it may be helpful to look at a small case such as $n=3$ when you get (terms with like exponents of $\varepsilon$ combined)
$$1-\varepsilon(a_1+a_2+a_3)+\varepsilon^2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)-\varepsilon a_1a_2a_3.$$ The coefficient of the linear term is the sum of the $a_i$s, the coefficient of the quadratic term is the sum of the products of all the pairs of the $a_i$s etc. The signs alternate.

Comment: ^Should be $\varepsilon^3$ in the last term. I really miss the ability to edit comment indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few terms look like

$$ 1 -\varepsilon \sum_k  a_k +\varepsilon^2\left(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+\cdots+a_1 a_{n-1}+a_2a_3+\cdots+a_2a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-3}a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}a_{n-1}\right)-\varepsilon^3\left(\sum_{0\leq j_1<j_2<j_3\leq {n-1}}a_{j_1}a_{j_2}a_{j_3}\right)+\varepsilon^4\left(\sum_{0\leq j_1<j_2<j_3<j_4\leq {n-1}}a_{j_1}a_{j_2}a_{j_3}a_{j_4}\right)+\cdots$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Localth! Is the way to interpret the $\varepsilon^2$ term (for example) is to fix $j_1=1$ and sum over all other indices until $n-1$, then to fix $j_2=2>j_1$ and sum over all indices greater than $j_1$ until $n-1$ and so on?

Comment: You want to fix $j_1=1$  and take the product of $a_1$ with every $a_k | 1<k\leq n-1$, then fix $j_1=2$ and take the product of $a_2$ with every $a_k | 2<k\leq n-1$. The notation ensures you sum over combinations instead of the *permutations*

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. For the $\varepsilon^3$ terms I suppose you would then fix $j_1=1$ and sum over the products $a_{j_2}a_{j_3}|1<j_2<j_3\leq n-1$ and so on? And this would be done up until we fix $j_1=n-3$ where would would sum over the products $a_{j_2}a_{j_3}|n-3<j_2<j_3\leq n-1$

Comment: Yes, for $\varepsilon^k$ the terms are found by summing every combination of $k$ $a$-terms (once each)